# How to stop hadoop spamming log with "WARN HadoopFileSystemOwner: found no group information for myname (auth:SIMPLE)"

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

I am running a spark app on yarn in AWS EMR and I am getting spammed by MBs of this error:
`19/09/30 17:09:29 WARN HadoopFileSystemOwner: found no group information for myname (auth:SIMPLE), using myname as primary group`

Following advice from [Cloudera here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Name-node-logs-are-spammed-with-quot-No-groups-available-for/td-p/151419), I tried `id myname` on my namenode and I see `myname` under uid, gid and groups.

`hdfs groups myname` on namenode also shows:
`myname : myname`

How can I fix or stop this spam of my log?

Comment: On the off chance that you see this and care to respond; did you ever manage to find a solution for this? I'm encountering the same problem and this looks like the only relevant content I'm able to find by googling.

Answer (score 0):

change/add above property in core-site.xml

```
<property> 
  <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name> 
  <value>yourname</value> 
</property>
```

Comment: It is currently set as `dr.who`. Also, I submit apps as more than just `myname` and so I want to avoid a solution that fixed `myname` but not for `myothername`

Comment: this doesn't work. Still getting warnings

Answer (score -1):

> The way 'hdfs groups' works is by sending an RPC request with the
> username to one of the NameNodes. When using the default
> ShellBasedUnixGroups plugin, the NameNode that received the request
> will run a 'id -gn username' command as a forked process on its own
> host and collect the output.

Source: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/User-not-returning-any-groups-for-hdfs-groups-lt-ID-gt/m-p/71759